# WAMPSERVER won't send emails in batch mode but does send from a web browser

Tags: php, email, batch-file, sendmail

I have a batch PHP program that had been running on a Linux box. I'm switching to Windows and WAMP. I created a .BAT file to run the PHP program in batch mode. If I use a browser, everything works great, but when I run the same program using a .BAT file, the PHP program runs perfectly (databases get updated, etc.) except the email is not sent at the end. When the batch file ends, the message "The system cannot find the path specified." is displayed. I don't know what path it is looking for. Obviously, it found the .BAT file, PHP.exe and the PHP application.

I suppose I could just have a browser Meta Refresh run the application once a minute but I would rather use the Task Scheduler to make it more like my prior Cron Job.

What could be stopping the emails from getting sent in batch mode?

Here is example PHP code that works from a browser but not in batch"

```
<?php
echo "Start of mail test";
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: QSOMAP <example@gmail.com>";
//$headers[] = "Bcc: Mike Saeger<example@gmail.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: N9MS <example@gmail.com>";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
mail("example@gmail.com", 'Feedback on QSOMAP Upload', "<b>This upload was made possible by a donation from ".strtoupper("Mike Saeger")."</b><br>"."This is text". "The following pins were added to your map:<br>" . "processed", implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Here is the .BAT job that executes the above code. It is a single line of code.

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.33\php.exe C:/wamp64/www/mailtest.php
```

A browser will send out this email. A .BAT file will not send the email.
Connecting my browser to this address, sends out the email. If I add ECHO statements, or database functions -- they all work fine -- just no email.

http://[myipaddress]/mailtest.php

The PHP mail command is working because it works when I run the PHP program using a web browser. It just does not work from a windows .BAT command.

Comment: Is it possible your site has configuration information not imported by the CLI execution? Maybe different INI settings?

Comment: Windows does not have a mail server by default. So how are you sending mail using the PHP `mail()` function without a mail server. I would guess when you run, whatever via the browser you are using some other mechanism, or you are on a server with a mail server

Comment: The PHP mail command is implemented with the Sendmail (c) 2004-2011, Byron Jones, sendmail@glob.com.au.  I'm using the Google SMTP server and my Gmail account.

Comment: tadman: That was it. According to phpinfo() Apache was using a different php.ini than php.exe was using. They both had a similar line: sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i", BUT the Apache php.ini had sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t" without the -i . Removing the -i  makes the mail command work in batch. Problem solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, tadman helped me solve the problem.

Apache and PHP.EXE were using different php.ini files and the one that worked is located in
`C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.54.2\bin`, which was used by the *WEB applications*.

Batch programs were using the one in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.33`.
While they both had a `sendmail_path = line`, Apache's php.ini had
`sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"` whereas PHP.exe was using `sendmail_path = "C: \wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"` which caused the mail command to fail.